# Title case a sentence - Which solution is better and why?

Tags: javascript, loops, map-function

I am new to programming. I have written a solution in two different ways, but would like to know what is considered a better solution, and why.

Additionally, in terms of performance, why would one be considered better?

Solution 1:

```
function titleCase(str) {
  str = str.toLowerCase();
  str = str.split("");
  str[0] = str[0].toUpperCase();
  for(i = 1; i<str.length; i++){
    if(str[i+1] == " "){
      str[i+2] = str[i+2].toUpperCase();
    }
  }
  str = str.join("");
  return str;
}
```

Solution 2:

```
function titleCase(str) {
  str = str.toLowerCase();
  str = str.split(" ");
  str = str.map(function(val){
    val = val.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + val.slice(1);
    return val;
  });
  str = str.join(" ");
  return str;
}
```

Comment: The first one fails with a string that has a space at the end.

Comment: Or just use [a library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/titlecase).

Comment: @anko I could use a library, but this is just a small challenge I was set, and would like to know which could be better

Comment: In the future, we have a [Code Review SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site for this sort of thing.

Comment: @Anko Did not know that. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Which solution is best?**

Your second solution is best but could be better by chaining the method calls on `str` and removing the unnecessary re-assignment of `val` within your `map`:

```
function titleCase(str) {
  return str
      .toLowerCase()
      .split(" ")
      .map(function (val) {
          return val.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + val.slice(1);
      })
      .join(" ");
}
```

Or using ES6 we can reduce the size of your `map` block with an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```
function titleCase(str) {
  return str
      .toLowerCase()
      .split(" ")
      .map((val) => val.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + val.slice(1))
      .join(" ");
}
```

I would say the most obvious reason for the second solution being best is that it is easier to understand. By using named methods like `map` it is clear from the start what kind of operations are being performed. It is not clear looking at a for loop that you are mapping values.

______

**Which is best for performance?**

I suggest that you test each with a large dataset. I suspect you will find there is actually very little difference between each approach and that the first will have a negligibly shorter execution time due to requiring less function calls.

Comment: I did not know you could do that type of .notation. Thanks

Comment: All these function return a string, so you are basically chaining together strings functions :)

Answer (score 1):

The second one is a lot better because it's immediately clear what happens without needing to figure out what side effects that loop construct has. One could also say that it's more [functional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming).

It can also be shortened to one simple chain, without that many variable assignments, which makes it even easier to understand:

```
function titleCase(str) {
  return str.toLowerCase()
  .split(" ")
  .map(function(val) {
    return val.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + val.slice(1);
  })
  .join(" ");
}
```

The more complicated loop structure in the first one is also the reason for two bugs:

- It doesn't title-case strings that start with a space
- It throws on strings that end with a space<sup>1</sup>

When looping from `1` to `length-1`, you should have used `str[i-1] == " "` and `str[i] = …`.

Also notice that it's generally considered a bad practise to assign two different types to the same variable. When dealing with a string and an array of characters, you should use two different variables for them, instead of `str` for both.

<sub>1: Admittedly, the same would happen in your second function had you used `val[0].toUpperCase()` instead of `.charAt(0)` (which yields the empty string instead of `undefined` for out-of-range indices)</sub>

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Is there a performance cost associated with reassigning the variable?

Comment: @Frenchiejnr: Unlikely. It's more a maintainability cost associated with the verbosity.

Answer (score -1):

I like the look of mine because it's easier to read, it uses a lambda function, I have a cheeky string array access and that's it:

```
function titleCase(str) {
  return str
    .toLowerCase()
    .split(" ")
    .map(word => word[0].toUpperCase() + word.slice(1))
    .join(" ")
}
```

Of course word boundaries are an issue.

Comment: Don't be scared of awesome Mr Downvoter!

Comment: "I like the look of mine" does nothing to explain why you like it better.

Comment: @AdrianLynch OP was not about ES6, It did not ask about what you like, but about which one is better and why. So your answer is not useful and is off topic.

Comment: OP: "Which of these two is best?" - Me: "Neither, this is better than both!" - That's an answer.